# When was the ligature (æ) removed from daemon and replaced with "ae"?

Tags: technology

A lot of older books, white papers, and even kernels used the word dæmon, rather than daemon, but at some point between now and the early 2000s that trend changed. Does anyone know when this trend changed? Does anyone know why it changed (if there's a reason the community cited at some point)<sup>[4](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6811)</sup>?

#### UPDATE:

I was able to locate references<sup>[1](https://www.csail.mit.edu/ctss-documents) [2](http://people.csail.mit.edu/saltzer/CTSS/CTSS-Documents/PSNs/psn-63.pdf) [3](http://people.csail.mit.edu/saltzer/CTSS/CTSS-Documents/CTSS_ProgrammersGuide_1966.pdf) [6](http://people.csail.mit.edu/saltzer/CTSS/CTSS-Documents/PSNs/psn-60.pdf) [7](http://people.csail.mit.edu/saltzer/CTSS/CTSS-Documents/PSNs/psn-53.pdf) [8](http://people.csail.mit.edu/saltzer/CTSS/CTSS-Documents/PSNs/psn-49.pdf)</sup> within the MIT historical archives with mention of the term, but there is no use of the ligature.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138887/discussion-on-question-by-nationwidepants-when-was-the-ligature-ae-removed-from).

Comment: RC♦ asked a quite relevant clarification question: "Can you clarify what you mean when you say that "kernels" used the ligature? It seems like you are probably referring to Unix kernels, but what does it mean for them to "use" the ligature? Do you mean use it in their character set? Use it in their documentation? Require users to enter it under pain of segmentation fault?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Statements marked * are based upon the online OED)*

**History**

The word appears to have originated with "δαιμόνιον" in ancient Greek.*  It then passed through the Latin "daemōn" and the Western European "demon" (French, Spanish, Portuguese, Catalan, German).*  Old English had the word "demon".*

The earliest cited use of "daemon" (with the ligatures) is from 1594 and both spellings continued to be used until the end of the 18thC* when "demon" won out.  The alternatives "daemon" and "daimon"* after that seem to have only been used in an antiquarian manner.  The use of a ligature in this period is stylistic only, unlike Old English where it was a separate vowel.[²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)#%C3%86_and_%C5%92)

**Technology**

From the late 19thC onwards the rise of the typewriter mitigated against the traditional printer's ligatures.  As computer printers became more common they also used a highly restricted character set (EBCDIC or ASCII-6, later ASCII-7), for instance it was common in the 1970s to receive letters from government printed entirely in uppercase monotype.  With lithography taking over from letterpress even some short-run books were typewritten and not set.  Hence "daemon" could only be set with the "a" and "e" as separate characters.

**Programs**

The earliest cited use of "daemon" is from 1971* a time when no standard computer would be able to set the ligature.  As others have pointed out, ASCII-7 and EBCDIC dominated the industry for many years.  Although **word processors etc.,** started to introduce Latin-1 and later Unicode, most **OSs** continued to use exclusively 7-bit ASCII and EBCDIC until the expansion of the WWW post 2008.[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Adoption)

It appears (further research needed) that "daemon" was adopted as an uncommon historic spelling to differentiate it from the standard "demon".  There also is a suggestion ("also interpreted") that it could be from the acronym: "*d*isk *a*nd *e*xecution *mon*itor" or "*d*evice *a*nd ...".*

**TL;DR**

"Daemon" was not commonly used prior to *NIX.  The ligature was only common in professionally set books prior to c. 2008.  Type- and computer- written material used non-ligature settings.

Comment: Good answer! Going back to the older spelling was the deliberate archaism and clever wordplay beloved of computer geeks.

Comment: It is more probably a _b_ackronym? /Since the system-'dæmon' _is_ a unix-concept (or sth from theology) I read the Q as 'what's usage pattern in *nix-lingo practice'? / Since the passage after "It appears…" is the actual answer: indeed, we need more research and references! EG Is QOP's observation correct in the first place, etc? (One additional idea: "professionally typeset" might also mean that with TeX *nix typesetting had an extremely _easy_ way to get at the ligature…)

Comment: "Although word processors started to introduce Latin-1... most OSs used exclusively 8-bit... until post 2008." -- Latin-1 *is* 8-bit, just like IBM CP 437/850 or Windows CP 1252. Each of those *do* include æ. So even the original IBM PC would have no issue displaying that character, and neither would Apple, Amiga, Atari, RiscOS, or whatever.  And I don't know which expansion of the WWW you refer to; the WWW was very much a thing for over ten years by then.

Comment: See the citation.  I would have thought a bit earlier, but this will refer to the massive consumer rather than geek expansion.

Comment: I would have called in a backronym, but the OED doesn't , "backronym" is itself a neologism.  As regards "professionally set", this is the TL;DR summary.

Comment: @Martin: "Geek expansion"? What is your citation intended to say? I just see that æ is not a typographic ligature but a distinct letter in many alphabets, which I already knew. The last computer I'd been using that could not display æ was the C64. 2008 is just wildly off (Unicode exists since 1991), as is the claim that 8-bit somehow automatically limits you to a through z. You can write Cyrillic, Thai, and Hebrew in 8-bit.

Comment: I've swapped the citation links back to where they should be.  Follow them to see what the citation actually says.

Comment: Have YOU read any of my comments? Unicode simply does not factor into this. 0x91 is æ in CP 437 (MS DOS). 0xe6 is æ in most ISO 8859 encodings. (0xbf in Latin-7.) IBM PC, Apple Mac, Atari ST, and Amiga had no issue whatsoever handling this. The whole paragraph is misinformed and misleading.

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't mean I agree with everything you say.  I've changed 8-bit to 7-bit to reflect ASCII rather than the byte size, I hope that clarifies things.  I've also emphasised the difference between word processor (and similar applications) and OSs.

Comment: It's still just **wrong**. But have it your way.

Comment: @Martin "disk and execution monitor" is the first appearance of the word daemon, without the ligature, which was presented in a white paper published in 1964 for the Project MAC. Not certain when the first appearance was with the ligature as I would've thought it'd be at the origin of the word itself.

Comment: That's interesting.  Have you access to the paper?  It predates the earliest quotation in the OED by 7 years and would be worth forwarding to them.  It also clears up the etymology.  Well done!

Comment: @Martin I updated the references with a few of my findings. I did see a document which mentioned the original and I could've sworn it was 1964, but I couldn't find that, so I posted the documents back to 1965.